# Is there a way to auto-rename files downloaded from websites, when navigating to a directory that already contains a file of that same name?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, rename

My work environment is Windows 10 Pro v21H1 (OS Build 19043.1110) running Chrome v92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (64-bit).  I am working on a large project which entails downloading assets, including .jpg, .png, .gif, and .webp images, as well as .pdf documents, from numerous websites to various directories on my local system.  These files are stores in a hierarchy of directories that are not necessarily tied to the websites that the files originated from.  Therefore, prior to saving the file, I often have to navigate to the proper directory.

The problem is, if a file of the same name already exists, I am prompted to manually change the name of the file I'm saving.  I'm wondering, is there a way to automate this process?  Following the Windows renaming structure of adding a numerical value in parentheses would be ideal but isn't required.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Chrome does auto naming: An existing "filename.txt" is automatically renamed to "filename (1).txt". Is this not working for you?

Comment: It auto-renames files, when I download a file, and don't change directories.  However, if I have to navigate to another directory, where a file w/ that same filename exists, I run into the problem I'm trying to solve.  For instance, if I download a file called 01.png, and the last save directory was "PNG Images," if there was a 01.png file already present in that directory, the file would be renamed 01(1).png.  But, if I navigated to "New PNG Images," and a file already existed w/ the name 01.png, I would be prompted to either manually overwrite or rename that file.

Comment: I think that's just the way that Chrome works. You may file a feature-request with the Chromium project, or write your own extension, but I don't know of another solution.